# I have made all the payments on a car I cosigned. Do I have to fight for possession of the vehicle?

Tags: loans, car, co-sign

I cosigned on a vehicle for my ex, yet he has made no payments. I have made all the payments so far even though he has always had possession of the car. I will continue to pay if he gives me the car, but if not I am going to let them take it from him. I know it will effect my credit but I am not going to keep paying for it for him. What do I have to do to get the car?

Comment: Is your name on the title? Did the two of you agree upon the arrangements going in to this? For example, what would happen if he stopped paying, who would own the car, etc.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: This may fall into legal liability on the ownership of the car, for which you would need a lawyer.  And you may want to look into who owns the *title* for the car, which regardless of the loan agreement is what would really determine who *owns* the car.

Comment: Judge Judy hears cases like this all the time.  Which means I think you'll need a lawyer.

Comment: Who made the payments has no bearing on who owns the car. It is all about the title.

Comment: @JohnFx I guess (as a moderator) you know which country Misty is in. The rest of us don't. Payment history *does* matter in some countries.

Answer (score 8):

Ordinarily a cosigner does not appear on the car's title (thus, no ownership at all in the vehicle), but they are guaranteeing payment of the loan if the primary borrower does not make the payment.

You have essentially two options:

1. Stop making payments for him.  If he does not make them, the car will be repossessed and the default will appear on both his and your credit.  You will have a credit ding to live with, but he will to and he won't have the car.
2. Continue to make payments if he does not, to preserve your credit, and sue him for the money you have paid.  In your suit you could request repayment of the money or have him sign over the title (ownership) to you, if you would be happy with either option.  I suspect that he will object to both, so the judge is going to have to decide if he finds your case has merit.

If you go with option 1 and he picks up the payments so the car isn't repossessed, you can then still take option 2 to recover the money you have paid.  Be prepared to provide documentation to the court of the payments you have made (bank statements showing the out-go, or other form of evidence you made the payment - the finance company's statements aren't going to show who made them).

Comment: For my first car, one of my parents cosigned and their name was on the title along with mine.